# Change SQL SERVER 2005 from default instance to named instance?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

I have installed SQL Server 2005 and now have instance name as the default one:

```
SERVERNAME
```

I'd like to change to:

```
SERVERNAME\MyDB
```

Is this possible? If yes, how?

Comment: i think its possible .. have a look on my answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, unfortunately it isn't possible to do this without a complete uninstall/reinstall of basically a new instance of Sql Server.

Answer (score -1):

It depends on the problem you can set an alias for the default instance, is like a nickname for instance, so any customer can see your named instance as you wish.

You can do this using the SQL Server Configuration Manager one of the Configuration Tools from SQL Server 2005 and above.

Comment: You would have to set the alias on every single machine that ever wanted to query your instance - aliases are a feature supported by the Sql Client libraries, they don't apply to the server in the sense that you set an alias once on the server and forget it.